# Import minified JavaScript code into HTML file without pasting in

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, newrelic

I have an SPA and adding newrelic analytics to the project. Newrelic provided me with a script tag with a bunch of minified code. I do not want to paste it in the html file because i can't use env variables, and it convolutes our html file. What would be a good way to import it as a script without pasting it in the file? i tried pasting it into a file and referencing it but not entirely sure if that is a good way to go about it.

In essence, instead of using

```
<script>
  window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n){if(!e[n]){var o=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n][0].call(o.exports,function(e){var o=t[n][1][e];return r(o||e)},o,o.exports)}return e[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return 
</script>
```

I want to do something like the following based on an env variable

```
<script src="/src/analytics/newrelic"></script>
```

Any advice would do.

Comment: I believe Google Tag Manager `document.write`s such scripts directly in to the page. So you'd end up with a script you include in the page that writes everything (including the script tags) in to the page. This would circumvent potential same origin restrictions but could conflict with some CSP policies.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the New Relic Browser agent from an external file is not supported:

Link: [Browser Instrumentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/page-load-timing-resources/instrumentation-browser-monitoring)

It may work, but if you encounter any problems, the first thing the support engineers will ask is how you are deploying the agent.

[image: Javascript placement]